# How do you write a select for the intersection of two condidtions in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to write a select query with the firstname and lastname of a person.
I have written queries for each. As I am using Microsoft Access, I can't get the intersection of the two. So What would be the another option for me to retrieve all the records with the letters of fname and lname of a person. The query I have right now is as follows:

```
select Registration_No, FName, MName, LName 
from Registration 
where FName like '" + fname + "%' 
    AND select Registration_No, FName, MName, LName 
    from Registration 
    where LName like '" + lname + "%' " ;
```

What should I change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

To construct a basic SQL command of this kind, you combine all your search stuff and put it after the WHERE like this:

```
select Registration_No, FName, MName, LName 
from Registration 
WHERE FName like '" + fname + "%' 
    AND LName like '" + lname + "%' " ;
```

Comment: I got another problem while executing a following code in jsp;                   <%stat3=conn.createStatement();
rsobj=stat3.executeQuery(query1);
while(rsobj.next())
{int charge = Integer.parseInt(rsobj.getString(4));
 rate1=charge+rate1;%> <tr>  
<td  class="label" colspan="3" align="left">Net Amount Payable</td><td class="database"  align="left"><%=rate1%></td>
</tr><tr>  
 <td  class="label" colspan="3" align="left">Due Amount</td>
<td class="database"  align="left"><%=rsobj.getString(6)%></td>
</tr><%}%>Here, as in while loop the rate appears many times; i want only final value to appear.

Comment: @Samiksh, you should add this as a new question